# How to go update every xml config file's IP Address in multiple folders where software was installed

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-parsing

I have a software that upon installation asks for the IP address of my server and stores that address into multiple config files in different folders. This code that I have updates the config file's endpoint address inside one config file.

How would I modify the code to look where the software has been installed and update all the IP addresses within ALL the config files inside different folders where the software was installed.

All of the config files with IP addresses look somewhat like the example I have.

**ConfigFile**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConfigTool
{
    class Class1
    {
    //    foreach (Environment.SpecialFolder folder_type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)))
    //    {
    //        DescribeFolder(folder_type);
    //    }
    //txtFolders.Select(0, 0);
    //const string FILENAME = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.);
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\******\***\***\*****\*****.****.****.exe.config";
        public static IPAddress GetIPAddress(string hostName)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            var replay = ping.Send(hostName);

            if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return replay.Address;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc =  XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                List<XElement> endpoints = doc.Descendants("endpoint").ToList();
                foreach (var endpoint in endpoints )
                {
                    string address = (string)endpoint.Attribute("address");
                    string newIp = "10.249.30.4";

                    string pattern = "//[^:]+";
                    address = Regex.Replace(address, pattern, "//" + newIp);

                    endpoint.Attribute("address").SetValue(address);
                }
            doc.Save(
```

**XMLExample**

```
<endpoint name="***Local" address="net.tcp://10.249.30.4:7732/EventSubscriberServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="****.Services.ServiceContracts.ISubscriptionService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="***Local" address="net.tcp://10.243.32.4:7732/EventPublishServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="****.Services.ServiceContracts.IPublishService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="*******" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="****" address="net.tcp://10.243.32.4:7732/AuthenticationServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="****.Services.ServiceContracts.IAuthenticationService" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

Comment: So what is your specific question? What part of this are you having difficulties with?

Comment: "How would I modify the code to look where the software has been installed, and update all the IP addresses within ALL the config files inside DIFFERENT folders where the software was installed."

Comment: That question is too broad. Is your question about finding the files, or updating the XML? Again, what is your **specific** question? Break what you want to do into tasks, and start working on one of the tasks. The first might be locating the files. Get that working. Then start working on how to update them. When you have code written for that first task and run into difficulties, you can ask for help with that specific code.

Comment: The code that I have commented out is the code written out for the task. I was trying to create an Environment.SpecialFolder to see where the software was installed and and run through the xml configs inside that directory but I'm not familiar with the Environment.Special Method. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: The code you've commented out is not a question. If your question is about using the `Environment.SpecialFolder` functionality, then edit it to ask about that topic. You need to ask a specific question, in the post itself, if you want help here. I've asked twice now for you to do so, and you've still not made an [edit] to your post to clarify what it is **specifically** that you're asking. (And as an aside, you can't just keep throwing wildcard `*` characters in and hope that it does something, because it  won't. A file path wildcard has to be valid.)

Answer (score -1):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<EndPoint> endPoints = doc.Descendants("endpoint").Select(x => new EndPoint()
            {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                address = (string)x.Attribute("address"),
                binding = (string)x.Attribute("binding"),
                contract = (string)x.Attribute("contract"),
                bindingConfiguration = (string)x.Attribute("bindingConfiguration"),
                behaviorConfiguration = (string)x.Attribute("behaviorConfiguration"),
                dns = (string)x.Descendants("dns").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value"),

            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class EndPoint
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string binding { get; set; }
        public string contract { get; set; }
        public string bindingConfiguration { get; set; }
        public string behaviorConfiguration { get; set; }
        public string dns { get; set; }
    }
}
```